# Removing spaces in complex names

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am trying to insert complex names like `Juan Carlos` but I want to remove all the spaces except the one between `Juan` and `Carlos`. Lets use `#` as space to see spaces better.

When inserting I have tried `RTRIM(LTRIM(@Name))` however It seems not to work, I tried to insert `###Jua#Car###` but when I select the field with `DATALENGTH([Name])` I get the lenght of `14`.

As I see that string I can count `13` characters, not `14`.

**1. What is the character I cannot count?**
**2. How can I end up getting `Juan#Carlos` removing all the spaces if LTRIM and RTRIM does not work?**

**Update with more info:**

The column datatype is nvarchar(100)
I just tried REPLACE([Name], ' ','') and the lenght i get is 12

Comment: You can use the `ASCII()` function to determine the hidden character in a `CHAR()` or `VARCHAR()`.

Comment: @jarlh nvarchar(100)

Comment: `DATALENGTH()` returns the number of bytes in a character, which is why you were getting 14 and 12 respectively - because you are using `NVARCHAR`, which uses 2 bytes per character. `LEN` will return the number of characters in a string, but it eliminates trailing spaces. Keep those things in mind when doing your calculations.

Answer (score 1):

You can trim non-alphanumeric characters using a somewhat complicated method:

```
select t2.name2
from t outer apply
     (select (case when name like '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'
                   then stuff(t.name, 1, patindex(t.name, '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'), '')
                   else ''
              end) as name1
     ) t1 outer apply
     (select (case when name1 like '%[a-zA-Z0-9]%'
                   then left(t1.name1,
                             len(t1.name1) - patindex(reverse(t.name), '%[a-zA-Z0-9.]%')
                            )
                   else ''
              end) as name2
     ) t2
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use in following, select separately FirstName, LastName and concat them with space:

```
DECLARE @FullName VARCHAR(MAX) = '  Juan Carlos  '

SELECT LEN(SUBSTRING(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FullName)), 1, CHARINDEX(' ', LTRIM(RTRIM(@FullName))) - 1) + ' ' +
       REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FullName))), 1, 
               CHARINDEX(' ', REVERSE(LTRIM(RTRIM(@FullName)))) - 1) )) AS [Len]
```

It returning `len = 11`